# Integrating Android Studio Plugin in Unity 3D

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to integrate Android Plugin to Unity 3D. I have been able to generate the working .jar file which I believe is the first step.
When I try to add it to Unity. It gives an error about my Manifest file:

```
Unable to find unity activity in manifest. You need to make sure orientation attribute is set to fullSensor manually.
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

What is the right way to add this plugin to Unity? (I want to use it as a UI element, if that helps)

Comment: What is your orientation attribute set to?

Comment: I also heard about the extends UnityPlayerActivity. I do not seem to know how to extend that also. It gives back an error.